# tinyMCE add class to the automatic <p> tag

Tags: jquery, tinymce

In the tinyMCE editor the text that I enter automatically is wrapped with `<p>`, which is fine. I just want to add a class to that `<p>`.

Note: I do not want to add a class to ALL the p elements, just the one where the user clicks and begins typing.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: In the tinyMCE editor the text that I enter automatically is wrapped with < p >, which is fine. I just want to add a class to that < p >. 

Note: I do not want to add a class to ALL the p elements, just the one where the user clicks and begins typing.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: which p tag are you referring too, the text itself is put in an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the tinymce javascript API for this purpose:

```
editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
$(editor.selection.getNode()).parents('p:first').addClass('your_class');
```

Here is a non-jquery solution:

```
editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
editor.selection.getNode().closest("p:first").setAttribute("class", "your_class");
```

Comment: You got a nonjquery version? (vue) but plain js is fine too

Comment: Thank you, do you also know a option to do this automaticly, like every P always has that class by default? I dont wanna attach default CSS propertys to the html tag itself cause this could mess up some stuff somewhere else and would be bad to maintain?

Comment: @Badgy: afaik it is possible to give all paragraphs in the ditor a class. Another option is to set your globas tinymce css so that your paragraphs get styled as if they had that class. In a second step you could give all paragraphs that special class just before you save the editor content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var tmceIframe = $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentDocument || $(".mceIframeContainer iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;

$(tmceIframe).find("p").addClass("test")
```

or as one line:

```
$($("iframe")[0].contentDocument || $("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document).find("p").addClass("test")
```

in the second example i make it shorter by going straight to the iframe, however, this could be an issue if you have more than one iframe on the page, u may want to use an element id to specify, like on the wrapper